# Font Size enlarge according to mobile font size setting

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixel

I am using cordova based mobile app which will load my web application into mobile as mobile apps. I set the font size in my web apps using pixels and notice that the font size will change according to mobile font size setting...is there any way to prevent font size change according to mobile font size setting using CSS/JS?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I did a quick search for the most up to date info and it does turn out that this is still not supported by all browsers. Possibly worth a try in your CSS though.

```
text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: I have try this but it is not working...as the font size will still change.

Answer (score 0):

One basic answer would obviously be tex size adjust and aset it to null but in cordova you must read the documentation to control app behaviour

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this might happen because of the way pixel's are rendered on a mobile device.

Adding the below line makes the rendering consistent.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag